# CSH if statement typo

Tags: csh

I can't seem to figure out where  the typo is, with a simple csh if statement.

```
 #!/bin/csh

 # Make sure the file is not too small
 set min_size = "250"
 set compfile_size = `wc -c $1_compile`
 echo $compfile_size
 echo $min_size
 if ( $compfile_size <= $min_size ) then
   rm $1_compfile
   echo "Comp File too small: $compfile_size" ; exit 1
 endif
```

Using the `echo $compfile_size`, I know it is there and what the size of the file is. When I run the script, I get back:

```
if: Expression Syntax.
```

Comment: Is it `$1_compile` or `$1_compfile` (with an f)?

Comment: Sorry, confusing variable/file name. If $1 = "blah" the file's name is "blah_compile". I am checking the size of the compile file, and named the variable compfile_size. I should have pickes something a little more different. The script above is successful in returning the size of the compile file. But not dong the if logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that this:

```
wc -c $1_compile
```

Outputs:

```
42 blah_compile
```

Which is obviously not a number.

So what you need to do, is just get the `42` part, for example with:

```
wc -c a | awk '{print $1}'
```

I've used `awk` here instead of the simpler `cut`, because the output of `wc` varies slightly depending on your system (GNU `wc` outputs as above, but BSD `wc` puts 5 spaces at the start of the line).

Comment: Yup.

I was looking at the output, and seeing the size, but not seeing that it should have just been the number. Thanks for the second set of eyes.